# Connecting to Raspberry Pi 4 wayvnc server from Ubuntu (ssvncviewer, gvncviewer)?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, vnc

I got a Raspberry Pi 4 that I did not set up myself; it reports:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 12 \n \l

pi@raspberry:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:    12
Codename:   bookworm

pi@raspberry:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 6.1.0-rpi4-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.1.54-1+rpt2 (2023-10-05) aarch64 GNU/Linux

pi@raspberry:~ $ ps axf | grep vnc
   1996 pts/0    S+     0:00              \_ grep --color=auto vnc
   1057 ?        SLl    0:00 /usr/bin/wayvnc --render-cursor --keyboard=us
```

So, apparently there is a `wayvnc` server running on it.

I try to connect to it from my Ubuntu machine, and I cannot. I found somewhere on the net that it is a good idea to port forward VNC over an ssh connection, so on my Ubuntu laptop I first did this:

```
user@laptop:~$ ssh -L 5903:localhost:5900 pi@192.168.1.248
```

... so then I could connect to `localhost:3` as VNC address instead of `192.168.1.248:0` - but that did not help.

My Ubuntu laptop reports:

```
user@laptop:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS \n \l

user@laptop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy


user@laptop:~$ gvncviewer localhost:3
Connected to server
Got credential request for 1 credential(s)
Error: The certificate is not trusted
Disconnected from server


user@laptop:~$ ssvncviewer localhost:3

Proto: RFB 003.008

Connected to RFB server, using protocol version 3.8

SelectSecurityType:
  sec-type[0]   19  (rfbSecTypeVencrypt)
Server did not offer supported security type:
 sectype[0] 19  (rfbSecTypeVencrypt)
  info: To connect to 'VeNCrypt SSL/TLS' you must use the SSVNC GUI
  info: or the ssvnc_cmd wrapper script with the correct cmdline arguments.
Security-Type:   0  (rfbSecTypeInvalid)  Latency: 5.90 ms

2023/12/01 11:20:45 VNC Viewer exiting.
```

So:

- I have no idea how to realize the "To connect to 'VeNCrypt SSL/TLS' you must use the SSVNC GUI or the ssvnc_cmd wrapper script with the correct cmdline arguments.":

if I just type `ssvnc` (which I assume is the "SSVNC GUI"), the only thing I can do it enter the following:

[image: ssvnc]

... and when I click on Connect, I get "WARNING: error fetching Server Cert: An Error occured in fetching SSL Certificate from localhost:3":

[image: ssvnc_error]

- I have no idea where to find this "ssvnc_cmd wrapper script" - my Ubuntu machine simply says:

```
user@laptop:~$ ssvnc_cmd
ssvnc_cmd: command not found
```

... but even if I found it, what options should I have used there?

So, how can I set up either the VNC server on Raspberry Pi 4 (wayvnc), or a VNC client on my Ubuntu machine (`ssvnc` or `gvncviewer`), so that I can just connect an use a VNC connection on my local network, without worrying about servers for root certificates, or whatever it is these error messages are complaining about?

---

EDIT: vinagre, with the below settings:

[image: vinagre setup]

... I first got a:

```
Error creating the ssh tunnel

Permission denied
```

... then, after re-entering the host settings, I finally get a prompt:

[image: vinagre prompt]

... and after I enter the correct password and hit Authenticate, I get:

```
Connection closed.

Connection to host 192.168.X.X was closed.
```

[image: vinagre connection closed]

If I do not have "Use host ... as a SSH tunnel" checked, and just use the IP address in Host (still on Protocol: VNC), I simply immediately get "Connection closed", without any password prompts.

So the question is still open - how do I make a VNC connection to this Raspberry Pi 4 (with Debian 12 bookworm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server has TLS enabled, use a VNC client that supports TLS.

TigerVNC is one such client, Vinagre is another. Both are provided by Ubuntu, I believe.

Comment: Thanks, I had accepted this answer, but I've just tried Vinagre, and it does not work (see edit to OP), so I've removed the accept; hopefully someone will tell me exactly what I have to do to get a connection going

Comment: Re-added accept, found how to use tigervnc, which worked

Answer (score 1):

what finally worked for me is TigerVNC; installed with:

```bash
sudo apt install tigervnc-viewer
```

Then I ran it by running `xtigervncviewer 192.168.X.Y` on the command line:

```
$ xtigervncviewer 192.168.X.Y

TigerVNC Viewer 64-bit v1.12.0
Built on: 2022-03-25 17:06
Copyright (C) 1999-2021 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.

Thu Dec  7 17:16:35 2023
 DecodeManager: Detected 2 CPU core(s)
 DecodeManager: Creating 2 decoder thread(s)
 CConn:       Connected to host 192.168.X.Y port 5900
 CConnection: Server supports RFB protocol version 3.8
 CConnection: Using RFB protocol version 3.8
 CConnection: Choosing security type VeNCrypt(19)
 CVeNCrypt:   Choosing security type X509Plain (262)
 TLS:         Could not load user specified certificate authority
 TLS:         Could not load user specified certificate revocation list
```

At first I get a screen, "Hostname (192.168.X.Y) does not match the server certificate, do you want to continue?":

[image: tigervnc-servercert-screen]

Upon clicking Yes, I get an "Unknown certificate issuer" window, which ultimately asks "Do you want to make an exception for this server?"

[image: tightvnc-unknown-issuer]

Note that `xtigervncviewer` saves this server (certificate?) as entry in a file `~/.vnc/x509_known_hosts` on the client machine - so next time you try to connect, the "Unknown certificate issuer" window will not be shown.

Upon clicking Yes, I get VNC authentication window:

[image: tigervnc-auth-window]

Upon entering my SSH username/password for the Raspberry Pi 4, finally I get a VNC connection of the Raspberry Pi 4 Debuian 12 desktop.